# Playing an .mp3 file with pyglet after downloading it with cherrypy server

Tags: python, python-requests, cherrypy, pyglet

I'm trying to play an .mp3 file after downloading it through cherrypy. I can download it to a temporary file but I can only play small .mp3 files, bigger files give a Floating point exception on pyglet.

Here's my server code:

```
import cherrypy
import os
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file

class Download:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, file_):
        tgt = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('./music', file_))
        return serve_file(tgt, "application/x-download", "attachment")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Download())
```

Here's my client code:

```
import requests
import pyglet


def download_file(file_):
    print(file_)
    data = {'file_': file_}
    r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/index",
                     params=data,
                     stream=True
                     )

    local_filename = './tmp.mp3'
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
    print(local_filename)
    return local_filename

src = pyglet.media.StaticSource(pyglet.media.load(download_file('b.mp3')))
player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(src)
player.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

My end goal is to have the client stream an .mp3 file from the server, but I'm trying to download the music file to the client first as it seems simpler to do for beginners. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to have an html tag that receives the mp3 file and streams it to the user.  The simplest way to do this is by doing something like this...

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, file_):
    tgt = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('./music', file_))
    return """
<audio controls>
  <source src="%s" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="%s" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
           """ % (serve_file(tgt, "application/x-download", "attachment"),)
```

Hope this helps!